# Uploading and retrieving files from django frontend to postgresql backend

Tags: python, html, django, database, postgresql

This is my table in postgres:

[image: Fields]

[image: Table]

How would I bring this into the frontend so that users can upload their documents without having to access the DB. Right now I can only upload docs into the filesystem instead of the DB:

views.py:

```
def upload(request):
if request.user.is_authenticated:
    username = request.user.username
if request.method == 'POST' and request.FILES['myfile']:
    myfile = request.FILES['myfile']
    fs = FileSystemStorage()
    filename = fs.save(myfile.name, myfile)
    uploaded_file_url = fs.url(filename)
    return render(request, 'app/upload.html', {
       "uploaded_file_url": uploaded_file_url,
       "username": username,
    })
return render(request, 'app/upload.html', {
    "username": username,
})
```

upload.html:

```
 {% if form.errors %}
    <p>You did not select a file to upload!</p>
{% endif %}

<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="file" name="myfile">
    <button type="submit">Upload</button>
</form>

{% if uploaded_file_url %}
    <p>File uploaded at: <a href="{{ uploaded_file_url }}">{{ uploaded_file_url }}</a></p>
{% endif %}
```

models.py:

```
class Document(models.Model):
Document_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='Document_name')
Date = models.DateField()
Client_id = models.ForeignKey(ClientDetail, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


def __str__(self):
    return self.Document_name
```

Schema:
[image: Schema]

Also how would I retrieve the uploaded documents.

Comment: Please also show the schema of that Postgres table. Is it a Django-managed model, or a separate database? (If it's a Django model, also show the model code.)

Comment: Edited original question. It is Django-managed model but i dont think we did a recent migration, hence the missing pdf, doc, ppt, xlsx fields in models.py

Comment: I can't believe that is the Django model you have, since it's missing the `pdf`/`doc`/`ppt`/`xlsx` fields that appear in the database table.

Comment: We're going to need the actual database definition – sorry to be blunt, but I don't care about whether you've done migrations or not.

Comment: Does that schema help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example for you:

settings.py

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls.static import static
urlpatterns = [
    ...
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

models.py

```
from django.core.validators import FileExtensionValidator
class Document(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='Document_name')
    date = models.DateField()
    client = models.ForeignKey(ClientDetail, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    myfile = models.FileField(validators=[
        FileExtensionValidator(allowed_extensions=['pdf', 'doc', 'ppt', 'xlsx'])
    ])

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import Document
class DocumentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Document
        fields = '__all__'
```

upload.html:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="ok">
</form>
{% if uploaded_file_url %}
    <p>File uploaded at: <a href="{{ uploaded_file_url }}">{{ uploaded_file_url }}</a></p>
{% endif %}
```

views.py

```
def upload(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated: 
        # Is it better to use @login_required ?
        username = request.user.username
    else:
        username = ''
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = DocumentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            doc = form.save()
            return render(request, 'app/upload.html', {
               "form": DocumentForm(),
               "uploaded_file_url": doc.myfile.url,
               "username": username,
            })
    else:
        form = DocumentForm()
    return render(request, 'app/upload.html', {"form": form})
```

Comment: In your models.py: myfile = models.FileField(...)

What would be the postgresql equivalent? Right now I have 4 different fields (ppt, doc, xlsx, pdf) using type bytea.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/file-uploads/#handling-uploaded-files-with-a-model